# Codeigniter: Retrieving data on button click with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a simple webpage which generates a random quote from my database upon refreshing the page. I wish to implement some AJAX and JQuery in order to generate quotes via the button rather than having to refresh the page. I have done some research but I am not sure how to implement this in Codeigniter. My current code is below...

Page controller:

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->model('quote_model', '', TRUE);
    $data['quotes'] = $this->quote_model->getRandom();
    $this->load->view('home', $data);
}
```

The view:

```
<?php include ('layout/header.php'); ?>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 quote-holder">
        <img src="application/assets/alan1.jpg" alt="..." class="img-circle img-responsive">
        <br>
        <blockquote class="text-center">
            <p><?php echo $quotes[0]['quote']; ?></p>
            <footer class="text-center"><?php echo $quotes[0]['character_name']; ?> in <cite title="Source Title"><?php echo $quotes[0]['series_name']; ?></cite></footer>
        </blockquote>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default center-block">Generate quote</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<?php include ('layout/footer.php'); ?>
```

Here is the function in the model I am retrieving the data from:

```
function getRandom() {
    $query = $this->db->query("
       SELECT * FROM quotes, characters, series
       WHERE quotes.series_id = series.series_id AND quotes.character_id = characters.character_id
       ORDER BY rand() 
       LIMIT 1
    ");
     return $query->result_array();
}
```

Should I simply be using something like this?

```
$("button").click(function(){
   $.get( "Page/index", function( data ) {
     //output data to page element...
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

getI would do something like: controller:

```
  public function callme()
{
    $this->load->model('quote_model);
    $data['quotes'] = $this->quote_model->getRandom();
}
```

Then in my footer:

```
condole.log("click button")
var_url = "controller/callme" // the url to the controller and method
$.get({
       url: url

      })
```

But meh, im bad at programming and even worse at jquery :D

Answer (score 0):

Make hidden input for offset

```
<button onclick="showmore()" value="showmore" />
<input type="hidden" name="offset" id="offset" value="15"/>
```

Now Your Ajax Call

```
function showmore(){
$.ajax({
    url:my_controller/showmore,
    data:{
      offset :$('#offset').val()

    },
    type:json, 
    success :function(data){
        $('#show-more').prepand(data.view)
        $('#offset').val(data.offset)
    }
})
```

}

Your Controller

```
function showmore(){
  $limit = '10';
  $offset = $this->input->get('offset');

  $result  = $this->yourmodel->getdata($offset,$limit);
  $data['view'] = $result;
  $data['offset'] =$offset +10;
  echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Your Model

```
$query = $this->db->get('your_table', $limit, $offset); 
        $data=$query->result_array();
        return $data;
```